# Can I use XXCOPY to archive windows folders/subfolders whose contents are unchanged for 1 year?

Tags: archiving

Need to identify and archive windows folders/subfolders where there has not been any activity in last 365 days. IE no new files or changes to files.  Does not HAVE to be XXCOPY, but XXCOPY is corp. approved

Comment: What version of Windows? Do you mean XCOPY?

Comment: I do mean XXCOPY.  I am unsure what exact op sys corp. will purchase except it will be windows.

Comment: We will need to know the operating system to provide a better answer for your situation. Do you know if the system will be Windows 7 or Windows 8? Does the current system have Windows Vista or XP? The reason I ask is because I know of a great command that would help and solve this problem

Comment: @Luke http://www.xxcopy.com

Comment: It most certainly will not be windows 8.  Will likely be a windows server version or windows 7.  I do have XP W7 and Server 2003 machines to experiment with.

Answer (score 2):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) (Robust File Copy) can probably help you with this.  It's part of the Windows Server Resource Kit for Windows 2003 and earlier, and Vista/Server 2008+ include it by default.

Use the `MINLAD` switch:

> /MINLAD:n :: MINimum Last Access Date - exclude files used since n.

So something like `robocopy c:\source\*.* d:\target\*.* /MINLAD:365` will copy all files from the Source folder to the Target folder, excluding anything accessed in the last 365 days.

More info: [Robocopy and a Few Examples](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx), and more info is also available if you type `Robocopy /?` at a Windows command prompt.

Alternative/additional "robust" file copying programs you could also try are covered in this SU question: [Intelligent file copy/move software?](https://superuser.com/questions/10721/intelligent-file-copy-move-software)

Comment: We already use XXCOPY to do what you suggest, but I need to archive the entire folder/subfolder structure or leave it entirely alone based on whether any files have been added or changed in last year.